# i would like to auto detect the environment and set the appropriate variables

Tags: mysql, node.js, environment-variables, dev-to-production

I have the same web application running on 2 different servers. It also runs on 2 different servers. Each of environment have its own database.
The file `config.json` contains every database informations.

**Developement environment**: The `app.js` and `database/db.js` files, are calling a file `getConf` which retrieves `config.json` informations with `preprod` object.

**Production**: I update the retrieved object from `preprod` to `prod`.

**Call**:

```
// Pre-production
var config = require('./database/getConf').preprod 

// Production
var config = require('./database/getConf').prod
```

I would like to do this automatically, which means, to update to production environment, I don't have to update any files. Just a copy paste from the dev but it detect automatically the environment and set the appropriate database.

I tried many modules like `nconf`, `dotconf`, and `config` but they all required to select the environment in the command line before launching the app.

 But my 2 apps are running in two different IIS servers in my company and they're launched from IIS and not from the command line.

I hope doing just a copy paste of the hole project folder from thedev to the prod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can find out pretty much every thing you need to know about the system with the module [os](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/os.html).

If you're looking for the CPU architecture : [os.arch()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_arch).

If you're looking for which type of OS : [os.type()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/os.html#os_os_type).

Hope it can help you ^^.

Comment: thank you you just made my day :)
i used os.hostname() to know in which server we are (they have same arch and type

Comment: is there a way to return the application pool or application name from the iis server ?

Comment: `require(__dirname + '/package.json').name`

Comment: in the package.json file it's the same name of the app but one is for development and the other is for production, i want to automatically detect the pool name of the app to know if it's the dev app or the prod app